# Get public IP in Golang

Tags: go

How do we get public IP in golang? Method `req.Header.Get("X-Forwarded-For")` returns array of IPs. How do we identify which one is public and which on internal? Is there any other method to fetch public(external) IP?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following IP blocks are reserved for private IP addresses.

```
Class        Starting IPAddress    Ending IP Address    # of Hosts
A            10.0.0.0              10.255.255.255       16,777,216
B            172.16.0.0            172.31.255.255       1,048,576
C            192.168.0.0           192.168.255.255      65,536
Link-local-u 169.254.0.0           169.254.255.255      65,536
Link-local-m 224.0.0.0             224.0.0.255          256
Local        127.0.0.0             127.255.255.255      16777216
```

You may write a function that checks for if the ip comes under these

Here is an attempt to do the same,the code below is not handling ipv6 please add if needed

```
func IsPublicIP(IP net.IP) bool {
    if IP.IsLoopback() || IP.IsLinkLocalMulticast() || IP.IsLinkLocalUnicast() {
        return false
    }
    if ip4 := IP.To4(); ip4 != nil {
        switch {
        case ip4[0] == 10:
            return false
        case ip4[0] == 172 && ip4[1] >= 16 && ip4[1] <= 31:
            return false
        case ip4[0] == 192 && ip4[1] == 168:
            return false
        default:
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Here is play [link](https://play.golang.org/p/fhcq7C3u4Lo)

Comment: Thank you, its was very helpful.

Answer (score 7):

Using an IP api will 100% give you your public IP :

```
type IP struct {
    Query string
}

func getip2() string {
    req, err := http.Get("http://ip-api.com/json/")
    if err != nil {
        return err.Error()
    }
    defer req.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return err.Error()
    }

    var ip IP
    json.Unmarshal(body, &ip)

    return ip.Query
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

type IP struct {
    Query string
}

func main() {

    m := getip2()
    fmt.Print(m)

}

func getip2() string {
    req, err := http.Get("http://ip-api.com/json/")
    if err != nil {
        return err.Error()
    }
    defer req.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return err.Error()
    }
    var ip IP
    json.Unmarshal(body, &ip)
    // fmt.Print(ip.Query)
    return ip.Query
}
```

Comment: Instead of copying the other answer, it's better if you [suggest an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66854089/edit).

Answer (score -3):

I use the following code for finding out public IP :

```
//function to get the public ip address
func GetOutboundIP() string {
    conn, err := net.Dial("udp", "8.8.8.8:80")
    HandleError("net.Dial: ",err)
    defer conn.Close()
    localAddr := conn.LocalAddr().String()
    idx := strings.LastIndex(localAddr, ":")
    return localAddr[0:idx]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will only work on networks that don't employ the use of NAT. Please revise your answer.

Comment: this may return an private ip as well in case when your machine is behind the NAT